# Set Image to included imageview in a layout

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

i try to say it simple.

i have to activities:

- Activity A > contains a imageview
- Activity B > A activity is included in it.

in activity B im trying to set image for imageview in activty A by codes. but i get force close!

```
ImageView iv =(Imageview) findviewbyid(R.id.activityAimageview);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
```

i was hoping if there is a way to set image for that imageview in activity A.

Comment: how can you get context of ACtivity A in B......

Comment: you can't access view of another activity! why you want do it?

Comment: @koutuk what do u mean?

Comment: im getting text from sever and i have if claus , so there is no way ? really? @Ahmad

Comment: so why you don't get text from server in activity B??

Comment: well in activity b is a list ! and iin activity a is the list adapter , u know i should get in ac A...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have a bad design issue.

One activity in another activity has no meaning. Every activity must be unique and be set aside for a specific task.

What you want to do, can be accomplished with: Fragments.

1. Don't touch Activity B.
2. Change Activity A to be a Fragment.
3. Add Fragment A next to the ImageView in your Activity B.

Then in activity B you can always use a `findviewbyid()` function (After `setContentView()`), and in Fragment A you can always access Activity B with `getActivity()` function.

To learn about Fragments start reading about them at:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: actully the A is fragment! yeah . Thanks for answer +1

Comment: You may accept the answer by clicking on the tick next to it or vote it up.

Comment: Yes, I am Iranian too. Nice to have you here Ali. Keep learning and keep asking questions.